# How to calculate the distance between two nodes that are not in direct range of each other?

Tags: unetstack

I want to localize node C (refer image below).Here we know the coordinates of A and B and A is in range of B and C so we can calculate the distance AC and AB using the ranging functionality.
I need to calculate the distance between B and C that are not in direct range of each other.I want to use the Law of cosines,
Is there a way to calculate the angle 'γ' represented in the below picture in UnetStack ?[Image Ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baHPO.png)

Comment: In your question you say A is in range of B and C, so you should know CA and BA. But you say you measure BC and BA ... did you mean CA rather than BC?

Comment: Yes ,sorry for the typo,Its CA and BA.I have corrected the ques.

Answer (score 1):

If you only know the lengths of 2 sides of a triangle, generally there are an infinite number of triangles that are are compatible with this knowledge. So, there isn't a way for you to figure out BC unless you have some other source of information.

This isn't about UnetStack being able to do it or not, but it is simply mathematically not possible, since your problem is under-constrained as stated above.